# Windows & Linux running at the same time

Tags: windows, linux, virtual-machine

Actually I have an Ubuntu 6.06.2 LTS server, but i need another server (windows server).

I know is possible to run them at the same time on the same machine, but i don't know how.

Any hint?

Is it possible to do this task without destroy the current server and do it all from ssh ?

Thank you

Comment: Why would you want this setup?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can set up a Windows Server virtual machine in Linux. [VirtualBox](http://virtualbox.org) can get you up and running free, assuming you've already attained a Windows license for Windows Server.

> Is it possible to do this task without
>   destroy the current server

Of Course!

> and do it all from ssh ?

Not easily. Remote access with [VNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/) (or a similar remote desktop program) will make it a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to install [VMWare](http://downloads.vmware.com/d/info/datacenter_downloads/vmware_server/2_0) or another virtualization product, and Windows on top of that.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu should come with [Xen](http://www.xen.org) utilities.  Install from Synaptic or aptitude.